# My Huawei B890 router is not accessible over the internet

Tags: networking, router, modem, nat

It may be a beginner question but I called my service provider and the manufacturer and they have no answer for me.

I want to have a remote access to my Huawei B890. On the management panel, I allowed the remote management and it says than I can reach this panel with this address : https://10.220.X.X:443. I can when I'm plugged but not over the Internet, on another machine.

When I go to the web site whatismyip.com, it says my ip address is 142.169.X.X. When I check on the router, it says than my IPv4 WAN Address is 10.220.X.X. As you can see, it's not the same

I tried to do the command 'ping 142.169.X.X' and I always have a timeout error.

I don't know which information can be useful and I don't have a configuration file. Please, ask if you need more information.

What can I do?

Comment: Be aware that it's a REALLY bad idea to enable remote management unless you have specific reasons to believe it's safe in this particular case. Doing so will open up several significant areas of attack.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I know it's insecure. This is the first test for what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

When you see a private IPv4 (10.x.x.x, 172.[16-20].x.x, 192.168.x.x) on the WAN interface of any router, that means there is another device between you and the public internet that is doing another Network Address Translation step.  If there's a cable/satellite/DSL/wireless modem connecting your Huawei to your ISP, check that device's WAN port for public/private IP.  If not, your ISP may have a way to map a port through, or a public IP, but likely will cost more.

Comment: Very instructive. It's a 4g router. I suppose by service provider map my router in their own network.... I'm very frustrated. They said they can't do nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chris Craft's answer:

A normal setup for IPv4 is like this:

```
                    1            2
Your devices ------- Your gateway ------- ISP and rest of the world.
                     e.g. the B890-75
```

All your devices (including the gateway) have their own public IP and can be reached.  The B890 would have to different IPs, and you can reach it from anywhere in the world without any problems.

Sadly this normal setup is rarely used for home users. The Internet has grown bigger than anticipated and we have almosr run out of IP ranges to give to people. To work around this many setups no longer request their own public IP range. Instead they use a single IP from their provider.  On the inside network they use RFC1918 IPs which are not routed and which are not reachable from the rest of the world.

This is called NATting and it breaks many things. But sadly it is needed with the current number of Internet users and IP v4. We could simply improve this (and we did, sicne 20 years we have IP v6 which solves this). But as long as most providers only provide IP v4 access we are stuck with NAT and workarounds sunch as port forwarding.

As I see it that leaves you only four options:

1. Ask your ISP for normal Internet access. Not for NATted access. They might even understand the question once you get past the first few levels of helldesk support.
2. Switch ISP's.
3. Created a tunnel to a server which has a publicly reachable IP.
4. Or assign IPv6 addresses. (cleanest solution, but that assumes that the B870 supports it.)

To recap:

```
           0        1            2
Your devices ------- Your gateway ------- ISP and rest of the world.
RFC1918            e.g. the B890-75
```

Devices at '0' and '1' have RFC 1918 IPs and are not reachable.
Devices at '2' ISpwards should be reachable and youy should be able to reach the public external IP on yout B890.

Now it gets ugly. Your ISP as also doing this ugly thing called NAT. As a result your B890's external IP is behind one and is unreachable. There are the same workarounds, but this time they would need to be done on the routers from your ISP, who is unlikely to cooperate.